# Multiple HeaderView for ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I wanted to know that is there any way to have multiple `HeaderViews` for a `ListView` or on the other hand i want to implement a `ListView` with three static rows at top and other rows with an adapter which will loaded from `AsyncTask`,according to ListView recycling i can't make three first row static by using position in `getView()` function of my adapter body. is there any suggestion to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap three views inside a layout (For example a vertical `LinearLayout`), and add that layout as the list header.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is static and always visible, then just put it **outside** of your listview, **above** it. And you should have the effect you need.

Comment: yes they are static but i want them to scroll with listview.

Answer (score 2):

I used this [Library](https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView) it was useful for implementing **Multiple Header ListView**, if the first three rows are static then you can add them statically first above the *ListView* then set the adapter for the *ListView* and in this case you don't need to use the library